# How to convert asp.net rewrite rule to .net core rewrite rule

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis

In Asp.Net I had a rewrite rule to abort processing when we encounter the tilde character to avoid IIS directory enumeration like this

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="([^\?].?.$)|([^\?].*$)"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="AbortRequest"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And so far in .net core I have this in program.cs

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("([^\\?].?.$)|([^\\?].*$)","",true);
```

So I am matching the same pattern with regex but how do I tell it to abort/stop processing? I dont want to replace it with something else.

Looking at microsoft documentation but not sure yet..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried AddIISUrlRewrite(), this will let you use same rewrite rule file. You need to make sure that the rules file is deployed with the app. Check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Yea I am trying that at the moment but I got an exception "wildcard syntax not supported" still working on it. Thanks

Comment: Still none the wiser, that MS link has a ton of rewrite stuff but nothing about aborting a request.

Comment: You don't need to convert it. [Asp.net core url rewrite middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#iis-url-rewrite-module-rules) can read rule from xml file directly. So you just need to store this rule as another .xml file and remove this rule from web.config.

Comment: Yea but .net core gives an error "Wildcard syntax is not supported" and if i remove that it doesn't like the asterix either with the exception "Invalid pattern '*' at offset 1. Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.'